# TclOO: cross-object namespace export/import

Tags: namespaces, tcl

How can one setup TclOO cross-object namespace transfer?

Specifically, in the example below:

- `runner` object needs to export its method namespace as commands
- and `invoker` object needs to import `runner` namespace for use as DSL

The following example in Tcl 8.6:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
namespace eval ::runner {
    ::oo::class create Runner {
        constructor {} {
            namespace export RUN
            puts "runner.export: [namespace export]"
        }
        method RUN {} {
            puts "runner.RUN"
        }
    }
}
namespace eval ::invoker {
    ::oo::class create Invoker {
        variable runner
        constructor {} {
            set runner [::runner::Runner new]
            set runnerNS [info object namespace $runner]
            namespace import ${runnerNS}::*
            puts "invoker.import: [namespace import]"
        }
        method process {} {
            puts "invoker.process: [RUN]"
        }
    }
}
set invoker [::invoker::Invoker new]
$invoker process
```

Produces this error:

```
runner.export: RUN
invoker.import: 
invalid command name "RUN"
    while executing
"RUN"
    (class "::invoker::Invoker" method "process" line 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TclOO methods are not commands. (Technically, it's because they have a different C signature.) To make this work, you need to create an extra command in the object that acts as a delegate for the method; the trick to doing this efficiently is to use `tailcall my` to do the dispatch.

```
oo::class create Runner {
    constructor {} {
        proc RUN args {tailcall my RUN {*}$args}
        namespace export RUN
        puts "runner.export: [namespace export]"
    }
    method RUN {} {
        puts "runner.RUN"
    }
}
```